# Как синхронизировать время в с удаленным NTP сервером

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

У меня есть уже написанное на Qt графическое приложение. Мне необходимо, чтобы в отдельном виджете или в уже имеющемся сделать поле, с синхронизацией времени и с выводом отклонения моего времени с временем NTP сервера, адрес которого я смогу менять в текстовом поле. Как реализовать в коде подключение к NTP серверу, получение от него времени и разницу во времени? Есть ли какие то библиотеки для этого? Если это невозможно, то как обратиться к сервису w32tm и получить от него корректные данные, т.к. например w32tm /monitor возвращает большое число строк которое нужно парсить, а хотелось бы сразу получить в int или double время и отклонение во времени

Comment: Приветствую. Смысл задачи понятен. На мой взгляд реализовывать NTP в своем приложении - не лучшая идея, я уверен, что суть проекта совсем не в этом, а времени и сил на реализацию потребуется достаточно много. Проще написать модуль, который будет взаимодействовать с внешним клиентом, а каким образом, ну дело творческое. Я в свое время именно так и поступил, что в дальнейшем позволило с легкостью перейти на PTP. Можно посмотреть в сторону https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp

Comment: DenSDS Спасибо, что откликнулись! Т. е. не бывает никаких api для связи с внешним NTP сервером?

Comment: я не встречал. Что вы под связью понимаете? NTP клиент не просто вычисляет отстройку между своим и серверным временем, он ее отфильтровывает и подстраивает системное время таким образом, чтобы ее минимизировать. Я не думаю, что реализовывать все это в своем приложении - хорошая идея. Это самостоятельная задача. Куда проще взаимодействовать с самим клиентом, и от него получать все необходимое.

Comment: Что вы под связью понимаете? Я имею ввиду например некий запрос getTime() к некому серверу точного времени и в ответе я бы получал время и отклонение моего времени от времени сервера точного времени